# How to get the linked table column value in view (Laravel5)?

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am a new to laravel can anybody help?

**Tables structure**

```
1) rooms
   id |roomno |roomtype_id  |luxurytype |status
2) roomtypes
   id| code| description
```

**Models code**

1) roomtype model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class roomtype extends Model
{
 public function rooms(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\room');
 }
 }
```

2)room model

```
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class room extends Model
 {
  public function roomtypes(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\roomtype');
  }
 }
```

**Controller**

```
 public function index()
 {
    $roomtype = roomtype::all();
    $rooms = room::all();
   return view('home', array('roomtype'=>$roomtype , 'rooms'=>$rooms));
 }
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($rooms as $rooms)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $rooms->roomno }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $rooms->luxurytype }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $rooms->roomtypes->description }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $rooms->status }}</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

**Error**
    If I use this line `{{ $rooms->roomtypes->description }}` then am getting:

> Trying to get property of non-object
>        (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hms\resources\views\home.blade.php)

How can I show the room with its roomtype description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller file like this

```
 public function index()
 {
   $rooms = room::with('roomtypes')->get();
   return view('home', array('rooms'=>$rooms));
  }
```

Now access room type in blade view in following way-:

```
   @foreach ($rooms as $rooms)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $rooms->roomno }}</td>
                <td>{{ $rooms->luxurytype }}</td>
                <td>{{ $rooms->roomtypes[0]->description }}</td>
                <td>{{ $rooms->status }}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```